# How to prevent non stop recursive function to run twice on scroll?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have 4 gif and 4 png images. It has a sequence like this:

1. first gif appears for 3 seconds, then hide and first png appear
2. second gif appears for 3 seconds, then hide and second png appear
3. third gif appears for 3 seconds, then hide and third png appear
4. fourth gif appears for 3 seconds, then hide and fourth png appear
5. Repeat step 1

This sequence will run only if I scroll down and appear in viewport.

This is the view:

```
<?php foreach($serviceTypes as $i => $type):?>
    <div class="service-item" id="service-item-<?=$i?>">
        <div class="service-item-icon">
            <img class="service-item-gif" src="<?=Url::base(true)?>/uploads/servicetypes/<?=$type->service_type_gif?>" alt="" />
            <img class="service-item-png" src="<?=Url::base(true)?>/uploads/servicetypes/<?=$type->service_type_icon?>" alt="" />
        </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Here's how I've done:

```
var gifIsPlaying = false;
function playGifService(index) {
    if ($(".service-list").length > 0 && $(".service-list").offset().top < $(window).height()) {
        gifIsPlaying = true;
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (index == 0) {
                $("#service-item-0 .service-item-gif").show();
                $("#service-item-0 .service-item-png").hide();
                $("#service-item-3 .service-item-gif").hide();
                $("#service-item-3 .service-item-png").show();
            } else if (index == 1) {
                $("#service-item-1 .service-item-gif").show();
                $("#service-item-1 .service-item-png").hide();
                $("#service-item-0 .service-item-gif").hide();
                $("#service-item-0 .service-item-png").show();
            } else if (index == 2) {
                $("#service-item-2 .service-item-gif").show();
                $("#service-item-2 .service-item-png").hide();
                $("#service-item-1 .service-item-gif").hide();
                $("#service-item-1 .service-item-png").show();
            } else if (index == 3) {
                $("#service-item-3 .service-item-gif").show();
                $("#service-item-3 .service-item-png").hide();
                $("#service-item-2 .service-item-gif").hide();
                $("#service-item-2 .service-item-png").show();
            }

            gifIsPlaying = false;

            playGifService((index + 1) % 4);
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

I call playGifService function first time in on scroll event. I use locomotive scroll, but it should be similiar to window on scroll.

```
scroller = new LocomotiveScroll(), scroller.on("scroll", function(t, e) {
    if (!gifIsPlaying) {
        playGifService(0);
    }
});
```

The problem is, when I scroll up and scroll down again (the gif and png is in viewport again), playGifService is running again. What could be the problem? Please help.

Comment: What is the use of `gifIsPlaying = true`?  You've got no check for `if (gifIsPlaying) return;` (or similar)